# How do I do variadic templates of variadic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

## Problem Statement

I'm trying to pass in a struct that contains a generic attribute like such

```
template <typename Value>
struct ColumnValue {
    std::string columnName;
    Value value;
};
```

I'd also like to create a function that accepts an unknown number of parameters as such

`print(T... args)`

These args will be of the type ColumnValue objects with 1 or more...

I'd like the print function to do different things depending on what type "Value" is.

## Desired Result

```
222
"hellooooo"
```

## Code

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Value>
struct ColumnValue {
    std::string columnName;
    Value value;
};

template <template<typename> typename ...X, typename ...Y>
void print(std::string firstArg, const X<Y>& ...args) {

    for(auto val : {args...}) {
        std::cout << val.value << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    ColumnValue<int> v{
        .columnName="hello",
        .value=222
    };

    ColumnValue<std::string> d{
        .columnName="hello",
        .value="hellooooo"
    };

    print("", v, d);

    return 0;
}
```

## Error Message

> : In instantiation of ‘void print(std::string, const X&
> ...) [with X = {ColumnValue, ColumnValue}; Y = {int,
> std::__cxx11::basic_string,
> std::allocator >}; std::string =
> std::__cxx11::basic_string]’: :28:19:   required from
> here :12:5: error: unable to deduce
> ‘std::initializer_list&&’ from ‘{args#0, args#1}’    12 |    
> for(auto val : {args...}) {
>       |     ^~~ :12:5: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘auto’ (‘ColumnValue’ and
> ‘ColumnValue >’)

Comment: `std::initializer_list` can only contain elements of a single type. You could use a fold-expression: `(std::cout << ... << args.value) << std::endl;`.

Comment: I'm addition `auto` can only be a single type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `ColumnValue` is a template doesn't make any difference for the signature of `print`. We can just take a regular parameter pack and let the compiler figure out the different types.

Secondly we can't loop over a parameter pack. We can however use a [fold-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

The end result would look something like this

```
template <typename... T>
void print(std::string firstArg, const T& ...args) {
    (std::cout << ... << args.value) << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to insert a newline between each argument, you would need some kind of helper for that. The simplest idea would be.

```
template <typename T>
void print_helper(const T& arg) {
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
}

template <typename... T>
void print(std::string firstArg, const T& ...args) {

    (print_helper(args.value), ...);
}
```